# Is it posible to get Outlook MailItem EntryID from from Windows Search ItemUrl

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, office-2013

If you perform Windows Index Search for an email or any outlook item it is not possible to get outlookItem EntryID.

Information you can get from Index Search is ItemUrl which is something like this:

**mapi://S-1-5-21-2127521184-1604012920-1887927527-71418/Mailbox – Some User ($484efb89)/0/Calendar/곯가가가걍걝걌곌겷걢곒갑겛개가검걟곔걙곾걤곂갠가**

Is it posible in C# get an EntryID from above mapi url?

Comment: What libraries are you using? Are logging into mailbox?

Comment: Is this what you looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868618%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found C# solution of the following link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/00491710-e245-452f-8b0a-56caa56277e4/how-to-open-mapi-urls-returned-from-wds-on-vista?forum=windowsdesktopsearchdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you will need to decode the search URL and extract the entry id. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960454.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff960506.aspx on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but is there any c# version of the code, or demo example.

Comment: I am not aware of one, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to get the EntryID from the Windows Search Index URL entry.I look for the Unicode chars in the URL which is something like
                // url mail example "mapi://{S-1-5-21-4283974727-3770627120-1224354217-1105}/Personal Folders($93bd4d7d)/0/2XX/가가가가걛객갹겠걸갨겵걀겡갯갉걉곦걽곁걹갤갢갣가/at=걥걫각가:Audit proposal.docx"

```html
/// <summary>
        /// Process a string to decode Unicode (Hangul) value to make Outlook EntryID. Pairs of hex digits make unicode chars
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sIn"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ProcessHangul(string sIn)
        {
            string sOut = "";
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sIn.Length; i++)
                {
                    int iCode = sIn[i];
                    string hexCode = iCode.ToString("X");
                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(i + " " + hexCode);

                    sOut += hexCode.Substring(2, 2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Common.LogError("ProcessHangul error", Ex);
            }
            return sOut;
        }
```

This is called as follows:

```html
string sHangul = "";
                    if (sURL.IndexOf("/at=") == -1) // if no attachment
                    { sHangul = Path.GetFileName(sURL); }
                    else
                    {
                        sHangul = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(sURL));
                    }

                    sEntryID = Common.ProcessHangul(sHangul);
```